# In honor of Lewis Carroll’s birthday, January 27

Tags: alphametic

Charles Lutwidge Dogdson, a.k.a. Lewis Carroll, is famous for his “ Alice's Adventures in Wonderland.”

He was born on January 27, 1832.
[image: alphametic about Lewis Carroll]

Comment: Even after looking at the solution in the answer, I was really confused about what was going on here mathematically, so I had to do some research.
Wikipedia says this is the usual notation for "long division" in "English-speaking countries": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Working bottom-up: `EL` minus a 2-digit is 1, so `EL` must be either 28, 55 or 82. We eliminate 55 because `E != L`, and we eliminate 82 because, if `L = 2`, then the second division can't be `LR - 27 = (2-digit)`.

> [image]

> Now `8R - ?? = ??`, so R can only be zero and the second division is complete (80 - 54 = 26). The first division is also complete since there's only one way `CA0 - ??? = 8`, judging by the last digit, as only `27*6=162` ends in 2.

> [image]

> The third division is `26o - ??? = ??`. It must yield a quotient of 9. There's also a 1 given in the remainder, so this one becomes `264 - 243 = 21`. Now the whole division can be completed.

> [image]

Comment: "fb RY zhfg or rvgure xx, xx be xx"(rot13, with numbers censored) I don't follow that, would you mind explaining?

Comment: @SamDean (Cbvag urer vf, gur fhogenuraq vf n zhygvcyr bs 27.)

Comment: @SamDean Hfvat ## nf n fgnaq-va sbe gjragl-frira: Gur rdhngvba jvyy or [RY - ##*k] jurer (##*k) zhfg or gjb qvtvgf fb "k" zhfg or rvgure bar, gjb, be guerr. Gung bayl tvirf guerr bcgvbaf sbe RY.